# Почему при использование margin-right двигаются от друг друга все слова. HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css

Я начинающий в `css`, `html`, `php`, `js`.
Решил сделать сайт, раньше был опыт, около 4 лет назад, сейчас все позабыл.

Я хочу что бы от правого края у меня отодвинулись слов.
Проблема заключается в том что когда я использую `margin-right: 100x`;
То у меня не только слова отодвигаются от правого края, но и сами слова от себя.

Вот скрины:
`margin-right:30px`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот если с `margin-right:100px`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код html:

```
<div class="text-options">
        <li><a href="#" class="jopo">Язык ▼</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Профиль ▼</a></li>
    </div>
```

А вот код css:

```
.text-options li{
display: inline-block;
float: right;
margin-right:30px;
list-style: none;
padding: 20px;}

.text-options li a{
color: #FFF;
text-decoration: none;}
```

В чем может быть причина?
Или `margin-right` за что то другое отвечает?
Нужна ваша помощ!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очень кратко:

- В данном случае лучше использовать отступ `margin-left` от каждого левого края элемента списка. Общий же отступ `padding` применить родительскому элементу от его внутренних краев.
- Позиционировать элементы можно с помощью Flex. Если у вас уже был опыт работы с `html` и `css`, то вам не сложно будет ее понять. Эта технология на самом деле очень проста.
- Изображение треугольников лучше выводить с помощью псевдоэлемента. Не стоит их заворачивать в тег `<a>`.
- В `HTML` все элементы списка `<li>` нужно заключать в тег `<ul>`.

Примерно такой должна быть ваша правильная верстка:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #383838;
}

.text-options {
  padding: 25px 50px;
  background: #242424;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}

.text-options ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row-reverse nowrap;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
}

.text-options li {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.text-options li:after {
  content: "▼";
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.text-options a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-options">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="jopo">Язык</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Профиль</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что вы задаете margin-right всем элементам вашего списка, чтобы добавить отступ только для одного, нужно задавать именно для него (мб слегка запутанно, сам только начинаю)

```
 <style>
    .text-options li{
        display: inline-block;
        float: right;
        list-style: none;
        padding: 20px;
    }

    .text-options li a{
        color: #FFF;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .first{
        margin-right:30px;
    }
</style>

<div class="text-options">
    <li class="first"><a href="#" class="jopo">Язык ▼</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Профиль ▼</a></li>
</div>
```

Сделал так, вроде работает :D